# PHP: Preg replace parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

What is the proper syntax to `preg_replace` just the parenthesis in PHP?

`$search = preg_replace('/\(\)/','',$search);`

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove both `(` and `)` from the `$search` string:

```
$search = preg_replace('/\(|\)/','',$search);
```

---

I think the fastest way to do this is using the `strtr` function, like this:

```
$search = strtr($search, array('(' => '', ')' => ''));
```

Comment: You don't need the extra wrapping `()` it is for exporting the pattern which in this case is unneeded.

Comment: @Tony: indeed! I have removed them.

Answer (score 12):

Here are my results of a little field test:

`preg_replace("/\(|\)/", "", $str): 1.590735912323`

`preg_replace('/[\(\)]/', '', $str): 1.3762638568878`

`strtr($str, array('(' => '', ')' => '')): 0.84079194068909`

`str_replace("(", "", str_replace(")", "", $str)): 0.80222821235657`

The last two are almost identical as J. Bruni pointed.

Comment: Add this to the benchmark: `preg_replace('/[\(\)]/', '', $str);` - and let us know the results.

Comment: So, a couple of str_replaces is faster than a single strtr... if the array could be avoided in favour of a couple of string parameters, maybe it should be faster... `strtr($str, '()', '  ')` - but this is not the desired behaviour... also, having several replaces, certainly strtr would win! :-)

Comment: Yeah, range looks faster. strstr and str_replace are almost the same, I cant find notable difference in the current test, they go up or down each time.. strstr would be more elegant solution though.

Comment: In regex, range is always faster than logic.  And string functions are always faster than regex when available.  Regex doesn't edge out string functions until you add complexity that results in the need for multiple string functions.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
$search = preg_replace('/[()]/', '', $search);
```

This will strip all parenthesis without regard to pairing.

Comment: case-insensitive parenthesis? :)

Comment: Typically this is just the beginning...force of habit. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is the proper syntax, though preg_replace is for regular expressions, if you just want to replace `()` then str_replace is a couple of times faster.

If you want to replace `(` or `)` wherever they are, you could use

```
preg_replace("/\(|\)/", "", $str);
```

Comment: Yeah but you'd have to use str_replace twice though right, one for each of the parentheses?

Comment: True, but I bet 5$ it would still be faster :P

Comment: @Tony: the `strtr` function can make several "str_replaces" at once. I use it in a basic templating class... instead of loop + str_replace, just a single strtr call...