# Remove last occurrence of Parenthesis PHP

Tags: php, regex

What I'm trying to do is remove a second or last set of parenthesis that I might have in a string.

```
$string = "Some text here (Some Text I want) (Title: Some Text I don't)";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

My regex is not too good so this example removes all parenthesis but I only want the last set to be removed.

Output should be `Some text here (Some Text I want)`

Note there is always a `:` in the last one if it's there.  If there is only one set of parenthesis it should `not` remove it. So if I already have `Some text here (Some Text I want)` it should stay that way.

Any help is great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Preg replace parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509564/php-preg-replace-parentheses)

Comment: @IGotRoot I've been here long enough to know that's not a duplicate. It doesn't not answer my actual issue. The code I have already removes them. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~^[^(]*\([^)]+\).*\K\([^)]+\)~', '', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/37), notice how only the second set of parentheses is selected (along with optional spaces). We replace that with the empty string.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[^(]*` matches any chars that are not the first opening parenthesis
- `\([^)]+\)` matches the first set of pars
- `.*` greedily matches anything, then backtracks up to the last set of pars
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\([^)]+\)` matches the last parenthesis
- We replace that with the empty string

Comment: it is always capturing second parenthesis, OP said last one. Check this link - http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/33

Comment: Thanks for the answer! upvote for putting an explanation of your code.

Comment: @PanamaJack This now ensures that the first set of pars is left untouched, and that only the last set (whether it comes second, third or later) is removed. :)

Comment: I like this because it's a one liner and still works.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're right, the lookahead was superfluous. You know how patterns evolve based on specs, like building a small object with timber... Often stepping back lets you remove unneeded supports... but it's all too easy to forget to step back. Nice catch, thank you. :)

Comment: Mine is prettier :-), and shorter and won't fail on this "Some text here (Some Text I want) (Some other Text I want)"

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix It's a bit buggy though—see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/38). :)

Comment: @zx81 read the OP's post and my answer which specifies that. Specifically "Note there is always a : in the last one if it's there." granted if there is other ":" in the preceding groups you would anchor it on the end of the string $, yours is "a bit buggy" too, it all depends on the data being checked, nothing is perfect.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Also that string `Some text here (Some Text I want) (Some other Text I want)` is impossible according to the specs, as the last set of pars will always contain a colon. When the specs give you more than you need, you have to choose what to use. In the path I chose, using the knowledge about the colon didn't seem necessary. It's like describing a building as being square and rectangular with flat sides. It's overkill, so we all choose one approach or the other.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix `yours is "a bit buggy" too` Sorry but no, I really don't think it is. But hey, not interested in arguing all day. If you have a valid string (according to specs) that doesn't work with my regex, then by all means make a demo on regex101.

Comment: Who's arguing? I simply stated your's was not accounting for the ":" which is a character specifically cited by the OP, that fact is if there ever is a case of 2 groups without the : your's will remove the second group, the OP says "Note there is always a : in the last one if it's there" not that there will only ever be 2 groups of parentheses with the last always having a ":" Where does he say there will only ever be 1 group if there is no end group with the ":" but "What I'm trying to do is remove a second or last set of parenthesis", here is your demo http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/38

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Again: If you have a valid string (according to specs) that doesn't work with my regex, then by all means make a demo on regex101. The demo you posted is not my regex.

Comment: Here is the link http://regex101.com/r/cO1lU3/2, you'll have to ask the OP what is the exact Spec and what variations we could expect.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Exactly my point. This string is impossible according to the spec, therefore my regex doesn't fail on it. Now will you please stop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56864/discussion-between-zx81-and-artisiticphoenix).

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is almost there but you can use negative lookahead:

```
$string = "Some text here (Some Text I want) (Title: Some Text I don't)";
echo preg_replace("/\s*\([^)]+\)(?![^(]*\()/", "", $string);
// Some text here (Some Text I want)
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jK3tX3/1)**

Comment: Didn't OP write **Output should be `Some text here (Some Text I want)`**

Comment: @FuzzyTree you're right. I just tested that right before you commented. anubhava can that be done to keep what's there if there is only one set of parenthesis?

Comment: If there is only one set of parenthesis I guess you want to get rid of that as well OR you always want to keep one set of parenthesis in the result?

Comment: Yes, the that's what I needed. where were you 3hrs ago. lol :) thanks for adding it.

Comment: Yes sorry have had a busy morning today so couldn't be online all time.

Answer (score 1):

I would determine the last index of ( and then delete everything after that.

Use strrpos to that effect. The function is documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the last set of parenthesis only if a) there are multiple sets of parenthesis and b) the last set of parenthesis contains a colon.

```
function removeLastParenthesis($string) {

    if(strpos($string,'(') === strrpos($string,'('))
        return $string;

    $beginning = substr($string,0,strrpos($string,'('));    
    $end = substr($string,strrpos($string,'('));
    $end = preg_replace('/\([^\)]*:[^\)]*\)/','',$end);
    return $beginning . $end;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/V7Jlw8ey)

Comment: thanks for this. I like the alternative. I used zk81 because it's a nice one liner and accomplishes what I need whether there is a colon or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_replace('/\(\w+\:.*?\)/', '', 'Some text here (Some Text I want) (Title: Some Text I don\'t)');
```

outputs

```
'Some text here (Some Text I want) '
```

-note- I'm assuming that "Note there is always a : in the last one if it's there." is true and that the part before the : will contain only a-zA-Z0-9_, as in the OP's example.

you might want to remove the trailing spaces too. for that use

```
preg_replace('/\s*\(\w+\:.*?\)/', '', 'Some text here (Some Text I want) (Title: Some Text I don\'t)');
```

**Explination:**

- \s* = one or more spaces ' '
- ( = capture '('
- \w+ = more then one 'a-zA-Z0-9_' or [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
- \: = ':' -- OP specified that the ending parentheses will contain this character if it exists
- .*? = any character ( non-greedy ) 0 or more.
- ) = ')'

also if this is always a single line with the ending ) at the end of the string you can add a $ to anchor it to the end. /\s*(\w+\:.*?)$/

Here is a more robust alternative

```
 preg_replace('/\s*\([^:]+\:[^(]+\)$/', '', '(dont:remove:me) (do : remove : me)');
```

output

```
'(dont:remove:me)'
```

Demo
http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/39

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex as well:

```
$string = "Some text here (Some Text I want) (Title: Some Text I don't)";
if(substr_count($string, '(') > 1 && substr_count($string, ')') > 1){
    $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '(')).substr($string, strrpos($string, ')') + 1);
}
```